# How to zoom in on plots inside an Rmarkdown presentation

Tags: jquery, html, css, r-markdown, ioslides

I am creating my first HTML - presentation with rmarkdown (ioslides) and would like to be able to manually zoom into a slide and navigate to an object.
Zooming works fine in a browser (crtl +, crtl mouse wheel) but I can not move the slide. Neither with the mouse nor with scrollbars. The latter do not appear as they do e.g. on a website.
Is there an appropriate way to implement such a thing or are ioslides not meant to be used like this?

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 (LXDE) and rstudio (R version 3.2.3). I tried zooming and navigating in Firefox and Chromium.

example:

````
---
title: Zooming into an ioslide
author: "Robatt"
output: 
 ioslides_presentation: 
 fig_caption: yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
 knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```
##The slide to zoom in and navigate

```{r fig.align='left', out.width = "100px", dpi=300, 
fig.cap="a small graph to zoom in, when necessary"}
library(ggplot2)
x=c(1:30,by=0.1)
y=x/(1+x)
ggplot()+
  geom_smooth(aes(x=x,y=y),se=F,span=0.15,color="grey20")+
  labs(x="you can only read me after zooming in")
```
````

*This also is the first time that I did not find an answer on stackoverflow and consequentially my first entry.*

Comment: Do you need to scroll or is this just about zooming in on plots?

Comment: I thought it would be easier to implement a possibility to scroll after zooming. But the jQuery works fine and is even a better solution! Many Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*I assume that your question is mainly about how you could zoom in on some tiny plots. Here is a solution using jQuery:*

---

We basically add a `div` container with an `img` element inside to our slides. Afterwards we integrate onClick functionalities to both, all the plots (aka `img` elements) and the image with class `zoomImg`. If you are clicking on a plot, it will be displayed inside our container and if you click on that container, it will vanish again. Here's the code:

````
---
title: Zoom in on Plots
author: "MS"
output: 
 ioslides_presentation: 
   fig_caption: yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
.zoomDiv {
  opacity: 0;
  position:absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 50;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #888888;
  max-height:100%; 
  overflow: scroll;
}

.zoomImg {
  width: 100%;
}
</style>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('slides').prepend("<div class=\"zoomDiv\"><img src=\"\" class=\"zoomImg\"></div>");
    // onClick function for all plots (img's)
    $('img:not(.zoomImg)').click(function() {
      $('.zoomImg').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
      $('.zoomDiv').css({opacity: '1', width: '60%'});
    });
    // onClick function for zoomImg
    $('img.zoomImg').click(function() {
      $('.zoomDiv').css({opacity: '0', width: '0%'});
    });
  });
</script>

## First Slide

```{r fig.align='left', out.width = "100px", dpi=300, fig.cap="tiny"}
plot(mtcars$cyl, main = "Plot 1")
``` 

```{r fig.align='left', out.width = "100px", dpi=300, fig.cap="tiny"}
plot(mtcars$mpg, main = "Plot 2")
```
````

This will result in the following presentation:

**No click:**

[image]

**Click on first plot:**

[image]

To make this work for a normal HTML document, change

```
$('slides').prepend("<div class=\"zoomDiv\"><img src=\"\" class=\"zoomImg\"></div>");
```

to

```
$('body').prepend("<div class=\"zoomDiv\"><img src=\"\" class=\"zoomImg\"></div>");
```

Comment: I also added `max-height:100%;
  overflow: scroll;` parameters to the `.zoomDiv` and now it is just perfect also for high sized images. So many thanks to you!

Comment: You're welcome. I will include your modifications in my answer.

Comment: can I just copy that script into any rmarkdown html document, or must I add something into my r chunks afterwards? I copied the script and add "out.width = "100px", dpi=300," into my r chunk, but it only makes the ggplot I have inside my r chunk really small... I can't click on it

Comment: So you are generating a simple HTML document?

Comment: Since you dont have `slides` element in a normal `html_document` the line `$('slides').prepend("<div class=\"zoomDiv\"><img src=\"\" class=\"zoomImg\"></div>");` must be changed to `$('body').prepend("<div class=\"zoomDiv\"><img src=\"\" class=\"zoomImg\"></div>");`

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer: is there any way to choose which plots are to have the zoom function or not?

Comment: Also: if you add your fix to the html document, pictures you click on to zoom longer down in the documents, will show up all the way up in the document, so you have to scroll up to see what you zoomed into :)

Comment: Ah good point, since a slide show stays in the same viewpoint I did not think about that. But give me until tomorrow to fiddle with that. Choosing images could be done be usign the chunk option `out.extra='class=\"zoom\"'` and then change `$('img:not(.zoomImg)')` to `$('img.zoom)')`  (did not try it, should work though ;))

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer I tried the example, and it works when you have `ioslides_presentation` as output but if you change the output to `flexdashboard::flex_dashboard`, it does not work.

Comment: Which is not totally surprising since I answered a question concerning presentations ;)

Comment: This is really great and can be added to R notebooks as well by storing the html code and adding this to the notebook header. 

```title: "Super Simple Popout Notebook"
output:
  html_notebook:
    includes:
      before_body: pop.html```

Comment: @MartinSchmelzer First, thanks for the solution. Second, did you ever find a way to get the zoomed image to stay on the screen (rather than having to scroll up) in a standard html document?