# Zoom function in rmarkdown html plot

Tags: html, r-markdown, zooming

Is there a way, like in this SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40401680/how-to-zoom-in-on-plots-inside-an-rmarkdown-presentation), to add zooming functionality to html_documents created with rmarkdown? I work in Rstudio. I have tried the following, but of course, it does not work:

````
---
title: Zoom in on Plots
author: "MS"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
.zoomDiv {
  opacity: 0;
  position:absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 50;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px #888888;
  max-height:100%; 
  overflow: scroll;
}

.zoomImg {
  width: 100%;
}
</style>


<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('slides').prepend("<div class=\"zoomDiv\"><img src=\"\" class=\"zoomImg\"></div>");
    // onClick function for all plots (img's)
    $('img:not(.zoomImg)').click(function() {
      $('.zoomImg').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
      $('.zoomDiv').css({opacity: '1', width: '60%'});
    });
    // onClick function for zoomImg
    $('img.zoomImg').click(function() {
      $('.zoomDiv').css({opacity: '0', width: '0%'});
    });
  });
</script>

## First Slide

```{r fig.align='left', out.width = "100px", dpi=300, fig.cap="tiny"}
plot(mtcars$cyl, main = "Plot 1")
``` 

```{r fig.align='left', out.width = "100px", dpi=300, fig.cap="tiny"}
plot(mtcars$mpg, main = "Plot 2")
```
````

I am very new to R-Markdown, and I don't know html nor JS, so this is quite hard for me.

Comment: I already gave the answer in the linked question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to zoom in on plots inside an Rmarkdown presentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40401680/how-to-zoom-in-on-plots-inside-an-rmarkdown-presentation)

Comment: Thank you, didn’t see it before

Answer (score 13):

Worked around Martin's solution, with a little bit of twist (centering an element in the viewport - the browser window).

````
# Insert this two chunks after YAML

```{css zoom-lib-src, echo = FALSE}
script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"
```

```{js zoom-jquery, echo = FALSE}
 $(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').prepend('<div class=\"zoomDiv\"><img src=\"\" class=\"zoomImg\"></div>');
    // onClick function for all plots (img's)
    $('img:not(.zoomImg)').click(function() {
      $('.zoomImg').attr('src', $(this).attr('src')).css({width: '100%'});
      $('.zoomDiv').css({opacity: '1', width: 'auto', border: '1px solid white', borderRadius: '5px', position: 'fixed', top: '50%', left: '50%', marginRight: '-50%', transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)', boxShadow: '0px 0px 50px #888888', zIndex: '50', overflow: 'auto', maxHeight: '100%'});
    });
    // onClick function for zoomImg
    $('img.zoomImg').click(function() {
      $('.zoomDiv').css({opacity: '0', width: '0%'}); 
    });
  });
```
````

After hitting the **Knit** button a document will be generated (and you may need to click on **Open in Browser** to generate the JavaScript).
Output (click on graph to zoom in / zoom out):

[image]

:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

EDIT for Quarto

```
# Insert this two chunks after YAML

<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js""></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').prepend('<div class=\"zoomDiv\"><img src=\"\" class=\"zoomImg\"></div>');
    // onClick function for all plots (img's)
    $('img:not(.zoomImg)').click(function() {
      $('.zoomImg').attr('src', $(this).attr('src')).css({width: '100%'});
      $('.zoomDiv').css({opacity: '1', width: 'auto', border: '1px solid white', borderRadius: '5px', position: 'fixed', top: '50%', left: '50%', marginRight: '-50%', transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)', boxShadow: '0px 0px 50px #888888', zIndex: '50', overflow: 'auto', maxHeight: '100%'});
    });
    // onClick function for zoomImg
    $('img.zoomImg').click(function() {
      $('.zoomDiv').css({opacity: '0', width: '0%'}); 
    });
  });
</script>
```

With reproducible example:

````
---
title: Zoom in and zoom out on Plots & Images in one click
author: "Matt Dzievit"
format: html
---

```{r}
#| label: setup
#| include: false
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

<script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js""></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').prepend('<div class=\"zoomDiv\"><img src=\"\" class=\"zoomImg\"></div>');
    // onClick function for all plots (img's)
    $('img:not(.zoomImg)').click(function() {
      $('.zoomImg').attr('src', $(this).attr('src')).css({width: '100%'});
      $('.zoomDiv').css({opacity: '1', width: 'auto', border: '1px solid white', borderRadius: '5px', position: 'fixed', top: '50%', left: '50%', marginRight: '-50%', transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)', boxShadow: '0px 0px 50px #888888', zIndex: '50', overflow: 'auto', maxHeight: '100%'});
    });
    // onClick function for zoomImg
    $('img.zoomImg').click(function() {
      $('.zoomDiv').css({opacity: '0', width: '0%'}); 
    });
  });
</script>

## Click on graph to zoom in / zoom out

```{r}
#| label: fig-plot-01
#| fig-cap: Plot 1
#| fig-alt: Plot showing the variation...
#| fig-width: 12
#| fig-height: 5
#| fig-align: 'center'
#| echo: false
plot(mtcars$cyl, main = "Plot 1")
``` 

```{r}
#| label: fig-plot-02
#| fig-cap: Plot 2
#| fig-alt: Plot showing the variation...
#| fig-width: 5
#| fig-height: 5
#| fig-align: 'center'
#| echo: false
plot(mtcars$mpg, main = "Plot 2")
```
````

UPDATE for R Markdown (.Rmd) & Quarto (.qmd), including raw content in the YAML header:

````
---
title: Zoom in and zoom out on Plots & Images in one click
author: "Matt Dzievit"
format:
  html:
    include-in-header:
      - text: |
          <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js""></script>
          <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
              $('body').prepend('<div class=\"zoomDiv\"><img src=\"\" class=\"zoomImg\"></div>');
              // onClick function for all plots (img's)
              $('img:not(.zoomImg)').click(function() {
                $('.zoomImg').attr('src', $(this).attr('src')).css({width: '100%'});
                $('.zoomDiv').css({opacity: '1', width: 'auto', border: '1px solid white', borderRadius: '5px', position: 'fixed', top: '50%', left: '50%', marginRight: '-50%', transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)', boxShadow: '0px 0px 50px #888888', zIndex: '50', overflow: 'auto', maxHeight: '100%'});
              });
              // onClick function for zoomImg
              $('img.zoomImg').click(function() {
                $('.zoomDiv').css({opacity: '0', width: '0%'}); 
              });
            });
          </script>
---

```{r}
#| label: setup
#| include: false
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## Click on graph to zoom in / zoom out

```{r}
#| label: fig-plot-01
#| fig-cap: Plot 1
#| fig-alt: Plot showing the variation...
#| fig-width: 12
#| fig-height: 5
#| fig-align: 'center'
#| echo: false
plot(mtcars$cyl, main = "Plot 1")
``` 

```{r}
#| label: fig-plot-02
#| fig-cap: Plot 2
#| fig-alt: Plot showing the variation...
#| fig-width: 5
#| fig-height: 5
#| fig-align: 'center'
#| echo: false
plot(mtcars$mpg, main = "Plot 2")
```
````

Or, as @LiangZhang suggested below, providing a file, ex: `zoom-in-out.html`, where we have previously placed our script:

```
---
title: Zoom in and zoom out on Plots & Images in one click
author: "Matt Dzievit"
format:
  html:
    include-in-header:
      - file: zoom-in-out.html
---
```

Comment: Do you know if this works as-is with quarto? I tried, but didn't work.

Comment: Hi @MattDzievit, see "Edit for Quarto" above. Also, you might be interested in exploring [lightbox](https://github.com/quarto-ext/lightbox) extension for Quarto.

Comment: This is awesome! Thanks, I definitely need to learn some javascript

Comment: For now, we could put those scripts in a separate .html file and use `include-in-header` option to add it. See [this](https://quarto.org/docs/output-formats/html-basics.html#includes) for how to add it properly. In this way, our .qmd file will look much cleaner.