# Display large image in Rmarkdown

Tags: html, css, r-markdown

I am trying to display a large image in an Rmarkdown html output without it being automatically resized. To do so, I want to place the image inside a `div` element (that is smaller than the image itself) that can be scrolled along the x- and y-axis.

This is what I have tried so far:

````
---
title: "test"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

<style>
  .container {
    overflow: scroll !important;
    white-space: nowrap;
    max-width: 300px;
    max-height: 300px;
  }
</style>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://images.hdqwalls.com/wallpapers/talking-to-the-moon-ym.jpg" width="2000px"/>
</div>
````

What I would like is to be able to display the image in its original size with scrollable elements along the two axis.

---

**Edit**

This is an illustration of what I am looking for:

[image]

Comment: You may want to look at the JQuery function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56361986/zoom-function-in-rmarkdown-html-plot/59401761#59401761).  The image should be displayed "in its original size with scrollable elements along the two axis".

Comment: Thank you for the reference, but it is not quite what I am looking for.

Comment: Maybe you just need to add ````img {max-width: 1000%;}```` inside ````<style>````, if I understood your question correctly.

Comment: @RadovanMiletić Does not seems to work. Nothing changes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hmm... when I run (**Knit**) the following code:

````
---
title: "test"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

<style>
  .container {
    overflow: scroll !important;
    white-space: nowrap;
    max-width: 300px;
    max-height: 300px;
  }
  img {
    max-width: 1000%;
  }
</style>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://images.hdqwalls.com/wallpapers/talking-to-the-moon-ym.jpg" width="2000px"/>
</div>
````

This is the output that I get:

[image]

Comment: It works! Don't know what happened when I tested the code in your comment, I must have mistyped something. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

````
---
title: "test"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

<style>
  .container {
    overflow: scroll !important;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>

<div class="container">
  <img src="https://images.hdqwalls.com/wallpapers/talking-to-the-moon-ym.jpg"     width="2000px"/>
</div>
````

Didn't know if this was possibly overlooked, just make `width =  100%` and `height = 100%`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. This unfortunately doesn't work. The image is resized to fit the `div`.