# Center slide header in middle of revealjs Quarto

Tags: quarto, reveal.js

I would like to center a slides header in the middle of the slide. It should actually look the same as in the title slide. I tried using `{.center}`, but that only centers vertically and not horizontally. Here is some reproducible code:

```
---
title: "Center slide in middle"
format: revealjs
---

## Slide {.center}
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see it is vertically centered but not horizontally. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to center the slide header in the middle of a slide in revealjs Quarto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

````
---
title: "Center slide in middle"
format: revealjs
engine: knitr
---


## Slide {.center}

```{css}
.center h2 {
  text-align: center;
}
```
````

---

[image: slide header centered]

Comment: Thank you @shafee! May I ask you if you know how to achieve this in my previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75922380/how-to-zoom-on-graph-in-slide-revealjs-quarto Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have seen that. And as @Julian pointed out, usiing lightbox is the closest approach but unfortunately lightbox does not seem to work with revealjs right now

Comment: Yes you are right! Thanks for checking!